# Unable to determine why JWT access token not working with Azure SQL. Connection fails Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, openid-connect

Trying to locate things to check, to clarify why an accessToken (JWT) appears to not work with Azure SQL. Any known trouble shooting steps to verify token claims, what Azure SQL checked and did not like in the JWT etc.

Azure AD has two users defined, who are members of an Azure Group.
Both users and the group were added to Azure SQL database xxyyzz using the Active AD user admin associated to the Azure SQL DB.

CREATE USER [aname@xxyyzz.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [aname@xxyyzz.onmicrosoft.com];

Both AZ AD users can connect to the Azure SQL database xxyyzz using Azure Data Studio.

Application registered with AD that was granted permission to delegate access to Azure SQL.

Application able to obtain JWT access token from AD, which it passes to Azure SQL via SQL Server JDBC driver 9.4.0.
Connection fails Login failed for user ''

URL
jdbc:sqlserver://xxyyzz.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxyyzz;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;

Properties
accessToken=....

Both unique_name and upn in the decoded JWT reflect the Azure AD User principal name aname@xxyyzz.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Can you reproduce the same error with the sample connection here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-token

Comment: The issue stems from the audience needing to be https://database.windows.net/.default
Seems to be a topic others struggled with and did not easily find in MS docs. Most blogs do not reference this either.